# Calculate distance between two GeoJSON features

Tags: .net-core, geojson, geojson.net

i'm using GeoJSON.Net library (https://github.com/GeoJSON-Net/GeoJSON.Net) to create some GeoJSON features in my code. Points, multilines etc. All that works fine until i need to calculate distance between some pair of features. This library does not have any ability to do that.

I've tried using GeoJSON.Net.Contrib.MsSqlSpatial (https://www.nuget.org/packages/GeoJSON.Net.Contrib.MsSqlSpatial) to convert features to SqlGeographies and then use the method on that type to calculate the distance. That works perfectly with one caveat: it's .NET Framework-only. The library is not available for .NET Core.

Please note, that I need an ability to calculate distance between two arbitrary features - points, multilines, polygons and not just between two points. This has to be done for SRID 4326 (WGS84).

Any idea?

Best regards, Dmytro.

Answer (score 0):

GeoJSON.Net is just a library to de-serialize GeoJSON according to RFC 7946.

For calculating distances you could either write your own implementation, or use one of the existing libraries like [Geolocation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geolocation/).

For convenience you can write some extension methods.

```
public static class PositionExtension
{
    public static double GetDistanceTo(this Position origin, Position destination,
        DistanceUnit unit = DistanceUnit.Kilometers)
    {
        return GeoCalculator.GetDistance(
            origin.Latitude, origin.Longitude,
            destination.Latitude, destination.Longitude, distanceUnit: unit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but you missed this part in my question: "I need an ability to calculate distance between two arbitrary features - points, multilines, polygons and not just between two points"

Comment: @DmytroGokun You can break it down to `IPosition` which holds lat/lon and is inherited through all classes dealing with coordinates. Points, multilines, polygons either inherit `IPosition`, or holding a collection of it. How you define the point of measure from a polygon for example, depends on your needs. You need to calculate this or maybe just iterate and find the smallest `IPosition` inside the collection.